# macOS Sierra doesn't support Acer X34 4k resolution with HDMI

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 4k-resolution

I just updated to macOS Sierra. 
My Acer X34 monitor doesn't work in 4k anymore, it used to work just fine with El Capitan. The max resolution option I get is 1080p. I'm using an HDMI cable because I don't have a mini display port to Display Port cable, and the DisplayPort is already connected to my desktop.
Suggestions?

Bonus: if you have any Razer devices don't bother updating to Sierra. They won't work either unless you uninstall Razer Synapse. Hura!

Comment: Same problem here, works fine in 10.11. I have two external Acer monitors, exactly the same. They work fine with DisplayPort but not HDMI. They appear to be detected as 30 inch monitors instead of 25 when connected via HDMI.  Been searching everywhere but haven't found anything online. Staying on El Capitan until this is fixed :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a 2k Acer XB2171HU. Was also working fine in 10.11 for me.

Comment: Apple fixed the bug in 10.12.1 Public Beta 2.

Answer (score 0):

OSX 12.1 solves this issue. It was released in beta and now it's in production.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem from time to time, now on OS10.12.6 with Acer4k2k monitor as external to my MacbookPro.  I disconnect cable, open laptop lid and reconnect cable and shut lid.  It seems to reset the monitor detection.